# Javascript prototype method override not found

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype-programming

I have this base type:

```
typeA = function () {

};

typeA.prototype = {
  do = function() { alert ("do something"); },
  doMore = function() { this.do(); }
}
```

and an inherited type typeB:

```
typeB = function () {

};
typeB .prototype = new typeA();
typeB.prototype.do = function() { alert ("do something else"); };
```

When I create an instance of typeB and call doMore, I get an error indicating that this.do is not a function.  Can I do this sort of thing in Javascript?

Comment: `do` is a reserved word in JavaScript. Probably related :p

Comment: Aside from your invalid syntax with the `=` operator, your code works fine. How about posting your actual code. Or if you want to post a reduced example, post one that actually illustrates your problem.

Comment: Reduced sample was overly simplified.  Problem was occuring within the call back to .each where I was using the 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this example what you are looking for?

```
typeA = function () { };

typeA.prototype = {
  do : function() { alert ("do something"); }, //use : instead of = here
  doMore : function() { this.do(); }
}

typeB = function () { };

typeB.prototype = new typeA();
typeB.prototype.do = function() { alert ("do something else"); };

var instance = new typeB();
instance.doMore();
```

You use `:` when declaring the properties of an object and `=` when assigning values to variables. :D

**Additional explanation:**

This is where the interesting stuff happens:

typeB.prototype = new typeA();

When you access a function or variable of an object with `.`, the browser first looks in the object itself to see if that variable is defined there. This is why you can do things like this:

```
var foo = function() {};
foo.prototype.bar = 3

instance = new foo();
alert( instance.bar ); //alerts 3
instance["bar"] = 55;  //add a variable to the instance object itself
alert( instance.bar ); //alerts 55, instance variable masks prototype variable
```

This shows how there are two ways that something can be 'in' an object. It can either be in the object itself (which you can also do by adding `this.bar = 55` to the constructor) or it can in the object's prototype.

Hence, when you say `typeB.prototype = new typeA();` you are putting everything in that instance of `typeA` into `typeB'prototype`. What you've basically said is "Hey browser, if you can't find something in an instance of typeB, look to see if its in this instance of typeA!"

Turns out there's nothing actually in that *instance*, just things in its prototype that end up getting used when the browser can't find a variable of that name in *that* object itself. When you call `instance.doMore()`, the browser can't find it in `instance`, so it looks in `typeB.prototype`, which you just set to an instance of `typeA`. Since it can't find anything called `doMore` in *that* instance, it looks in *its* prototype, and finally finds a definition for `doMore` and happily calls it.

One interesting thing is that you can still mess around with things that are actually in that instance of `typeA` that you set to be the prototype:

```
//earlier code the same

foo = new typeA();
typeB.prototype = foo;
foo.do = function() { alert ("do something else"); };
//^^ same as `typeB.prototype.do = function() { alert ("do something else"); };`

var instance = new typeB();
instance.doMore();
```

While this is kind of cool when you understand what's going on IMHO, the extra layer of indirection (checking to see if stuff is defined in the instance of typeA before looking in typeA.prototype) is probably not the best idea, and your code would probably be clearer if you just said this:

```
typeB.prototype = typeA.prototype;
```

(sorry if you already knew everything I just told you, but I thought I'd describe how things were working under the hood ;)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.  After reading this and returning back to my code, I realized my problem.  Sample was over simplified.  Within method do, I was using the .each to iterate over an array.  Within .each callback I was using the 'this' keyword to reference method 'do'.  But 'this' was refering to the item of the array and not an instance of typeB, hence my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the word `do` because it is a reserved keyword (used in do while loop). You can, however, try this:

```
typeA.prototype = {
    "do": function() { ... }
    ...
};

typeA["do"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use constructor functions when working with prototypes.

What you have to do is instantiate the object be after you set its prototype of typeA. What you're doing is dynamically adding they new function of .do() to be after typeB is created. That is the only way you can do that.

```
function typeA() { };
typeA.prototype = {
    'do': function () { alert("do something"); },
    doMore: function () { this.do(); }
}
function typeB() { };
typeB.prototype = new typeA();
typeB.prototype['do'] = function () { alert('doing from typeB'); };
var b = new typeB();
//
b.do();
```