# Javascript override prototypes method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Maybe someone can explain to me, why I can't override the method moep from B's prototype-class. I've found an example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148960/javascript-prototype-method-override-not-found) and if I'm overriding the function with B.prototype = ... it works. So why do I have to specify the .prototype to override the function?

Greetings - Thomas

```
A = function() {
    this.moep = function() { 
        alert("Im in class A!");  
    };
};

B = function() {
};

B.prototype = new A();
B.moep = function() { 
    alert("Im outside!");  
};

var keks = new B();
keks.moep(); // Alerts "Im in class A"
```

Comment: B's constructor is now A's constructor, so when you call new B(), you're getting an A - set B's prototype.constructor to itself

Comment: @kinakuta: *"B's constructor is now A's constructor"* No, it isn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm, care to explain?

Comment: @kinakuta: What's to explain? :-) You said that `B`'s constructor is now `A`. That's not true. The *prototype* assigned by the `B` constructor is an object created (once) by `new A`. That's a totally different thing.

Comment: Ok, when I say B's constructor, I mean B.prototype.constructor, which I thought could be inferred by the second part of my statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning to `B.moep`, not `B.prototype.moep` or (within `B`) `this.moep`. `B.moep` isn't involved in the prototype chain at all.

When you create objects via `new <functionname>`, the object's prototype is set from `<functionname>.prototype`. So if you want to override the `moep` assigned by `A` to the instance created by `new A` and assigned to `B.prototype`, you need to assign to `B.prototype`.

Comment: FWIW, if you're interested in doing class-like hierarchies in JavaScript, I've written a small toolkit script for that called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/). Even if you don't want to use it directly, the techniques it uses may be useful, full (commented) source is available.